# What's the difference between the English client versions?

Tags: diablo-iii, battle.net

When I go to download the Diablo III game client from Battle.net, I have a choice between three different clients if I intend to play in English: English (US), English (EU), and English (SG).

- I know that it's not determining which servers I can access, because there's a ["Global Play"](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/5203654/Introducing_Global_Play_for_Diablo%C2%AE_III-5_1_2012) concept, which means everyone can play on whichever server they want.
- I know the client is not used to determine the "home" region either, because the "Global Play" page also says that:

  > players will create characters and play in their "home" region, which is determined by where they live (specifically, *the country of residence registered to their Battle.net account*)

So, what **is** the difference between the clients? Which should I install?

Comment: While I'm not a 100% of the answer, I would suggest going for the EU version if you live in Europe and or play in that "home" region. US for the Americas and SG for Asia (SG is Singapore).

Comment: It is difficult to tell now, I tried multiple searches but didn't find any official explanation. We should wait the decryption and compare various English installation to see the differences. I decided to install enUS version but you can probably choose any English versions because, as you already said, any client version allow you to play; the region that you select during installation is the discriminant that defines the time you are able to login and the server region is going to host your games.

Comment: Install the version from the region where you live if you want to play at launch. Global Play won't be enabled until after all the regions are live, so if you have the US version you won't be able to play in Europe until the game also launches in the US. Since this is a time-localized answer, I decided to just post as a comment.

Comment: @StrixVaria Source for this?

Comment: @Drake I'm terrible at remembering sources, but my memory for the content of what I read is pristine. You're going to just have to trust me.

Comment: @StrixVaria I trust you, but maybe not the source :) The problem is that I live in EU and I downloaded en-US version, so now I am afraid that I cannot play today at midnight but I have to wait tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Drake That is exactly what will happen. It was an official Blizzard source (probably Bashiok), but I can't find it again.

Comment: @Drake maybe this is what you're looking for: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4917621943#1

Comment: I think the "home region" is bound to your battle.net-account, rather than the client, though. Otherwise everybody could just download the asian clients and play ... in the next couple of hours or so (don't know when it unlocks for Asia)

Comment: @StrixVaria I had the enUS version and luckily played without a problem on Europe region at launch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overall, there's not going to be much difference. It will boil down to things like:

- different EULA
- different pre-selected Server (EU for EU and Americas for US)
- links in the game leading to different websites (e.g. http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/ instead of http://us.battle.net/d3/en/ )
- "information window" on the title screen (like it exists in SC2 and WoW) will probably receive the displayed text from different servers.

And things like that. Furthermore, it's probably an easy tool for Blizzard to dispatch region-specific changes to a certain client only. E.g. the European Union introduces some crazy law that forbids the use of roman numericals, then Blizzard could patch only the EU version and replace all the III with 3s.

Comment: Spelling might be different too. Hopefully Armour rather than armor for non-US English etc. Find out soon I guess.

Comment: I don't think so. At least, there hasn't been any difference to my knowledge in past Blizzard games (e.g. my English(EU) Starcraft 2 installation still has armor instead of armour).